# Java iText not displaying images after converting

Tags: java, pdf, type-conversion, itext

So what I am trying to achieve is to convert HTML to PDF wtih images.

Just for text conversation I am using `iText`

and there is my code:

```
    public void downloadTemplateAsPdf() {

            try {
                InputStream content = null;
// Object Id for Html stream
                String objID = this.actData.getMainActs().get(0).getId();
                ContentStream cmisStream = folderCatalogue.getDocumentContentStream(objID);
                content = cmisStream.getStream();
                File fileTmp = File.createTempFile("tempFile", "pdf");
                OutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(fileTmp);
                Document document = new Document();
                PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, fileStream);
                document.open();
                XMLWorkerHelper worker = XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance();
                worker.parseXHtml(writer, document, content, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                document.close();
                fileStream.close();

//encode title for UTF-8 letters
                String title = URLEncoder.encode(templateTitle, "UTF-8");
                StringBuilder fileName = new StringBuilder(title);

                if (title.contains("+")) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < title.length(); i++) {
                        if (title.charAt(i) == '+') {
                            fileName.setCharAt(i, ' ');
                        }
                    }
                }
    // JSF primefaces <p:fileDowbload> to download file
                streamedContent = new DefaultStreamedContent(new FileInputStream(fileTmp), cmisStream.getMimeType(),
                        fileName + ".pdf");
```

I have checked http://itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker/html-images

and [iText HTML to PDF for non-english content images are very small in PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206803/itext-html-to-pdf-for-non-english-content-images-are-very-small-in-pdf) but all what I checked is somehow different.

Any help would be appreciated.
If I should give more info, just tell what.

EDIT:  example of my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html><style>body{ font-family:Arial,Verdana,sans-serif; }</style><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head><body><p><img src="image/9efc807d-352a-410d-9bf9-17ada2772bac.png"/></p>
</body></html>
```

And if i paste  src url to browser, it will open my  image file

Comment: Could you also attach the image? I tried to reproduce this with an image I had on my pc, but the image showed correctly.

Comment: oh, I solved problem, later I will post both methods, when converting html to Pdf and html to docx,  with embbed or linekd images and utf -8 letters.

Comment: Community waiting for your solution...